# Magento2.2.2 Backend Curl CURLPROTO_HTTP undefined

Tags: php, backend, magento2.2.3, curl

This is an odd one: I've just updated my to macOS High Sierra installed missing extensions Frontend it's all good Backend Admin login fine But when logged in get Exepction:

```
> 1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Exception): Notice: Use of undefined constant CURLPROTO_HTTP - assumed 'CURLPROTO_HTTP' in /Library/WebServer/Documents/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php on line 50
```

It doesn't make sense curl details are bellow:

```
curl -V
curl 7.54.0 (x86_64-apple-darwin17.0) libcurl/7.54.0 LibreSSL/2.0.20 zlib/1.2.11 nghttp2/1.24.0
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtsp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: AsynchDNS IPv6 Largefile GSS-API Kerberos SPNEGO NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz HTTP2 UnixSockets HTTPS-proxy
```

php -i

```
...
curl

cURL support => enabled
cURL Information => 7.54.0
Age => 3
Features
AsynchDNS => Yes
CharConv => No
Debug => No
GSS-Negotiate => No
IDN => No
IPv6 => Yes
krb4 => No
Largefile => Yes
libz => Yes
NTLM => Yes
NTLMWB => Yes
SPNEGO => Yes
SSL => Yes
SSPI => No
TLS-SRP => No
HTTP2 => Yes
GSSAPI => Yes
KERBEROS5 => Yes
UNIX_SOCKETS => Yes
PSL => No
Protocols => dict, file, ftp, ftps, gopher, http, https, imap, imaps, ldap, ldaps, pop3, pop3s, rtsp, smb, smbs, smtp, smtps, telnet, tftp
Host => x86_64-apple-darwin17.0
SSL Version => LibreSSL/2.0.20
ZLib Version => 1.2.11
...
```

Disabled warning give :

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function Magento\Framework\HTTP\Adapter\curl_setopt() in /Library/WebServer/Documents/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/HTTP/Adapter/Curl.php:78
```

Line 78 is `curl_setopt`:

```
protected function _applyConfig()
    {
        // apply additional options to cURL
        foreach ($this->_options as $option => $value) {
            curl_setopt($this->_getResource(), $option, $value);
        }

        // apply config options
        foreach ($this->getDefaultConfig() as $option => $value) {
            curl_setopt($this->_getResource(), $option, $value);
        }

        return $this;
    }
```

I don't get it I have curl installed any one any ideas? Thanks.